# calculate SVG path length in PHP like getTotalLength() in JS

Tags: php, math, svg

I'm trying to modify SVG files via a PHP script and at one point I need to calculate the length of some path elements.

In JavaScript, there's the handy function `.getTotalLength()`, but I wasn't able to find a PHP parser for SVG that offers something similiar, so I guess I'll have to manually parse the `d`-attribute and calculate the paths.

Loading the XML, getting the attribute etc. is not the problem, but I'm not very good at mathematics and especially not in the field of vectors. Let's take this example:

```
<path d="m 268.87448,476.05362 c -25.0135,11.49888 -35.53725,21.39636 -29.14819,47.61221 -0.79153,89.53821 7.5531,195.5936 -11.71546,284.63588 -24.02796,67.23588 -51.61983,89.1027 -112.32477,124.52935 0,0 -38.977804,16.40902 -54.19931,20.52688" />
```

What I would do first is `explode` the path by spaces and iterate through the result, then check whether it's a letter or a number and act accordingly. And that's where I'm stuck and don't even know how to begin.

I have read the SVG path specs at https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html - but still can't get my mind around the number crunching.

Comment: paths are not necessarily space separated 3-1 is valid and is the co-ordinate 3, -1 for instance.

Comment: Yeah, thought about that as well, but it doesn't matter for now. I'm creating the initial SVGs and can make sure that the format is space separated. Once I have the calculations, I could still modify it to take that into account (e.g. by parsing character for character). But good point for any other readers.

Comment: I think the question is too broad, there are lots of different things in paths and calculating the length of just one of the non-trivial ones would be an article in itself. Here's a solution in C++ FWIW http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/gfx/2d/Path.cpp

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine that it's not that trivial... Any hints to a PHP SVG parser library that comes with a built-in function equal to JS's `.getTotalLength()` will also be appreciated and accepted as an answer, if breaking down the maths behind it is too much for SO, and provided that such library exists and I have just not been able to find it.

Comment: Questions asking for libraries are off topic.

Comment: Remember also that nearly all SVG rendering libraries are open source.

Comment: Inkscape is [open source](https://inkscape.org/cs/download/source/) and has a feature called Extensions->Visualize Path->Measure Path... Now if someone can figure out how to use Inkscape command line `com.njhurst.filter.measure_length` to measure the path in a script.